# PostgreSQL - Add key to each objects of an JSONB array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

My database contains a table which has a column with **jsonb type**, and I want to update a part of these data using **functions/operators from postgreSQL**. Given we have this:

```
{
  "A":[
    {"index":"1"},
    {"index":"2"}
  ],
  "B":[
    {"index":"3"},
    {"index":"4"}
  ]
}
```

Let's say we went to add a key with an empty array to objects from "A" array, in order to have:

```
{
  "A":[
    {"index":"1", "myArray":[]},
    {"index":"2", "myArray":[]}
  ],
  "B":[
    {"index":"3"},
    {"index":"4"}
  ]
}
```

**How can I proceed?**

I've already tried this kind of things without success:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = (myColumn::jsonb)->>'A' || '{"myArray":[]}'
```

---

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = (
  SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(
    element, 
    array['A'], 
    to_jsonb(((element ->> 'A')::jsonb || '{"myArray":[]}')::jsonb)
  ))
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(myColumn::jsonb) element
)::json
```

---

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = (
  SELECT jsonb_each((element ->> 'A')::jsonb) || '{"myArray":[]}'::jsonb
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(myColumn::jsonb) element
)::json
```

Obviously, all of these tests have been big failure. I have difficulties to understand how works postgreSQL functions.

Somebody can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach with `jsonb_array_elements` and `jsonb_set` was the right idea, but somehow you nested them the wrong way round:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = jsonb_set(myColumn, '{A}', (
  SELECT jsonb_agg( element || '{"myArray":[]}' )
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(myColumn -> 'A') element
));
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=49c675337963365ef97ce007618f1b5a))</sup>

Btw if your column already has `jsonb` data type, you shouldn't need any casts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! But I added some changes because in fact, my column was `json` :') so I have included "myColumn" into a `to_jsonb()` ;)

Comment: had to add `WHERE jsonb_array_length(myColumn -> 'A') > 0`;

Comment: @fedor.belov The query was written under the assumption that every json object has an `A` property that is an array. If that's not the case, yes, you need to add a condition or create the array.

Comment: Thanks for this! May I ask how this "element" works in there? Did not get it honestly

Comment: @denyzprahy It's an alias for the relation returned by the `jsonb_array_elements` function. You can add `AS` before it to clarify. It ambiguously denotes either the column or the whole single-column relation iirc.

Comment: @denyzprahy See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM and in detail https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS