# How can I update all values in an array dynamically in jsonb column?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm working with knex in a node.js project on a PostgreSQL db. Will be using knex.schema.raw (raw SQL) to accomplish this.

I need to update all instances of a grade name ("1st", etc) in the "grades" array of a json object in a jsonb column. "grades" are one value in the whole json object, which is a lesson.

The array currently contains something like 
`"grades": ["Pre-K", "K", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th"]` and it needs to become `"grades": ["PK", "K", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]`.

Basically I need any instances of

`["Pre-K", "K", "1st", 2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th", "11th", "12th"]`

to be

`["PK", "K", "1", 2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]`

Is there a way to check the contents of a jsonb array, get the index of a grade, and update that index with the desired grade? Or another way to transform array data in a jsonb type column?

*(My initial idea was to create a list of every permutation of combination of `["Pre-K", "K", "1st", 2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th", "11th", "12th"]`, and just swap out the desired array out of data that exists, but that seems a bit ungainly, though technically possible. With this, though, I would still need to find the index of item in array in jsonb cell.)*

Comment: I don't know your full criteria, but with the example you posted you could just strip any lowercase characters?

Comment: @ConnorBurton if that includes dashes, yes that would work. How would I go about that? (I'll revise question to show what I have and what I want)

Comment: Don't try to update by index. Just update the whole array at once, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58959906/1048572)

Comment: What exactly does the jsonb column contain? An object with a `grades` property, or the plain array?

Comment: @foureyedraven my suggestion was doing this in JS, if you wanted a query solution I am not sure. In JS if you get the plain array you could do `a.map(value => value.replace(/[a-z-]/g, ''))` just using some regex to remove lowercase letters and hyphens

Comment: An object with the grades property. I edited question to try to reflect that better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression to eliminate redundant substrings.

```
update my_table
set json_col = jsonb_set(
        json_col, 
        '{grades}', 
        (
            select jsonb_agg(regexp_replace(value, 're-|st|nd|rd|th', ''))
            from jsonb_array_elements_text(json_col->'grades')
        )
    );
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c6bc5b7c5f055fd30557ee3ff3784181)

A simpler and faster version (though might be considered a bit hacky):

```
update my_table
set json_col = jsonb_set(
        json_col,
        '{grades}',
        regexp_replace(json_col->>'grades', 're-|st|nd|rd|th', '', 'g')::jsonb
    )
```

Read more about [POSIX Regular Expressions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you!! First one works well. Glad to know more about manipulating jsonb data.