# Postgresql and jsonb - inserting a key/value into a multi-level array

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

Very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959678/postgresql-add-key-to-each-objects-of-an-jsonb-array), but I struggle to adapt from their solution..

My table : `public.challenge`, column `lines JSONB`

My initial JSON in `lines` :

```
[
  {
    "line": 1,
    "blocs": [
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "abc"
      },
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "def"
      },
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "ghi"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "line": 2,
    "blocs": [
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "xyz"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Desired update :

```
[
  {
    "line": 1,
    "blocs": [
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "abc",
        "type": "regular"
      },
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "def",
        "type": "regular"
      },
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "ghi",
        "type": "regular"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "line": 2,
    "blocs": [
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "xyz",
        "type": "regular"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So basically I need to add the `type` key+value in every object of `blocs`, for each element of the root array.

My unsuccessful attempt looks like this :

```
UPDATE public.challenge SET lines = jsonb_set(lines, '{}', (

    SELECT jsonb_set(line, '{blocs}', (
        SELECT jsonb_agg( bloc || '{"type":"regular"}' )
        FROM jsonb_array_elements(line->'{blocs}') bloc
    ))

    FROM jsonb_array_elements(lines) line
))
;
```

(currently it sets the whole column as null, maybe due to `jsonb_set(lines, '{}'` while my json begins as an array ?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jsonb_array_elements` to unnest  all the array elements and then add the required json and use `jsonb_agg` to aggregate it again:

```
with cte as
 (select id,
         jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(val1,
                             '{blocs}',
                             (select jsonb_agg(arr2 || '{"type": "regular"}')
                                from jsonb_array_elements(arr1.val1 - >
                                                          'blocs') arr2)))
    from challenge, 
         jsonb_array_elements(lines) arr1(val1)
   group by 1) 
update challenge 
   set lines = (cte.jsonb_agg) 
  from cte 
 where challenge.id = cte.id
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9f308b741163485c4d5e88d396cef7ff)

Comment: Great thanks! By any chance, I'd like the value to be `arr2->'oldType'` (instead of always "regular"), how would you concatenate this in the jsonb_agg function ?