# Postgresql & jsonb : WHERE <a specific nested field in my json> IS NOT NULL

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

Table `public.challenge`, column `lines` JSONB

My initial JSON in `lines` :

```
[
  {
    "line": 1,
    "blocs": [
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "abc"
      },
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "def"
      },
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "ghi"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "line": 2,
    "blocs": [
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "xyz"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Desired result (add a new object `wrapper` for every `bloc`) :

```
[
  {
    "line": 1,
    "blocs": [
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "abc",
        "wrapper": {
          "nestedName": "abc",
          "type": "regular"
        }
      },
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "def",
        "wrapper": {
          "nestedName": "def",
          "type": "regular"
        }
      },
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "ghi",
        "wrapper": {
          "nestedName": "ghi",
          "type": "regular"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "line": 2,
    "blocs": [
      {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "xyz",
        "wrapper": {
          "nestedName": "xyz",
          "type": "regular"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have the following query (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67990051/postgresql-and-jsonb-inserting-a-key-value-into-a-multi-level-array)) :

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT id_lines,
          jsonb_agg(
                  jsonb_set(val1, '{blocs}',
                      (
                        SELECT jsonb_agg(arr2 ||
                                         json_build_object(
                                             'wrapper', json_build_object('nestedName', arr2->'name', 'type', 'regular')
                                             )::jsonb
                            )
                        FROM jsonb_array_elements(arr1.val1->'blocs') arr2
                        WHERE arr2->'name' IS NOT NULL
                          )
                      ))
   FROM public.challenge, jsonb_array_elements(lines) arr1(val1)
   GROUP BY 1
)
UPDATE public.challenge SET lines=(cte.jsonb_agg) FROM cte
WHERE public.challenge.id_lines=cte.id_lines;
```

The condition `WHERE arr2->'name' IS NOT NULL` does not filter out blocs where name is null, I struggle to find out why.. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to distinguish between SQL NULL and JSON `null`.

The `IS NOT NULL` predicate tests for SQL NULL, which would mean that the attribute is not present in the JSON.

To test for JSON `null`, use

```
WHERE arr2->'name' <> 'null'::jsonb
```

The type cast to `jsonb` is not necessary and would be performed implicitly.